# Is this possible with the SELECT LIKE specification?

Tags: sql

Looking at this link: [SQL SELECT LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

What if you were searching for a name that starts with `H` and ends with `dinger`?

Would I use:

```
SELECT NAME LIKE

  'H_dinger'
  'H...dinger' or
  'H%dinger' ?
```

I'll assume `H_dinger` would think there is only 1 character in between, but I don't know what it is -- so I'm searching for it.

`H...dinger` isn't valid.

And `H%dinger` seems like it would check it all, but on the site, that isn't even listed?

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Server? If so, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: And yes, `H%dinger` will find names that start with `H` and end with `dinger`, with any number of characters between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `%`, which is the variable-sized wildcard.

But you need to get the syntax right, such as with:

```
select NAME from TABLE where NAME like 'H%dinger'
```

Keep in mind that queries using `%` *may* be a performance issue (depending on how it's used and the DBMS engine). It can prevent the efficient use of indexes to speed up queries. It probably won't matter for small tables but it's something to keep in mind if you ever need to scale.

Comment: @Dwelling, tangential to the question (I have a habit of giving more than is asked for sometimes) but I've added a little more explanation.

Comment: Index will be used if the LIKE term does not start with `%`.

Comment: Actually, even `%xyz` can be efficient depending on how you set things up (reverse indexes as one example). That's why I said "may" and made it dependent on use.